# Android Java - Merge Recording Files

Tags: android, recording

I'm working on an Android app has the recording feature, so user can record and pause many times thus the app will record to many files, and if a user clicks PLAY we will need to merge all the audio files to one file to play. My question is what is the best way to merge all files and what is the file format we should use to save the recording file? Currently I can save with mp3/wav file but it will take much time (maybe 1 min) to merge some files into one file. Do you know what is the best way to merge many audio files in a few secs?
Thanks.